# Why does not return app React-Native OAuth

Tags: react-native, oauth-2.0

I am trying to authorize with the reat-native-auth package. When I change the values ​​in the config for example: clientId or redirect_url, the site where I perform the authorization operation returns me an invalid client_id or invalid redirect_url error. But when I try to log in with the correct values, after entering username and password for login processes, the browser is just waiting. It's just waiting. I wonder if there is a problem with my transactions?
I think the problem is caused by the android emulator, here are my codes:

```
export default class App extends Component {
  login = async () => {
    try {
      const result = await authorize(config);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  };
  render() {
    this.login();
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>asdasd</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I tried all these authentication processes using Linking, but the room reacted in the same way.
The scanner is just waiting like a white screen.

[image]

android/app/build.gradle :

```
  android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.oauth"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        manifestPlaceholders = [
            appAuthRedirectScheme: 'androidapp://foo'
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The main thing I think you need here is the ability to troubleshoot:

- Capture OAuth messages with a tool such as Fiddler / Charles Proxy
- Verify that the authorization response is returning to the app as expected
- Get an alternative AppAuth sample working with your configuration settings

**POSSIBLE WHITE SCREEN CAUSES**

- One cause is when there is no **User Gesture** during a redirect, though this tends to be intermittent, whereas your issue seems permanent
- Another is when the **net.openid.appauth.RedirectUriReceiverActivity** is not configured correctly in your manifest file, to pick up the authorization redirect response

**RESOURCES OF MINE**

Getting Android AppAuth working reliably is tricky and took me some time. If it helps I have a few resources that may give you some ideas and something to compare against. They are not coded in React Native though, so may not be a complete answer to your question:

- Getting the [Basic AppAuth Sample](https://authguidance.com/2018/02/20/android-setup/) working
- Getting [HTTPS Proxying of Messages](https://authguidance.com/2018/02/21/android-https-debugging/) working
- [Advanced AppAuth Sample](https://authguidance.com/2019/09/29/basicandroidapp-execution/)